# How to make Puppeteer's waitFor work? It blocks execution in current form

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, delay, wait

```
async function clickElement(page){
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('bzsjyuwj ni8dbmo4 stjgntxs ltmttdrg gjzvkazv');
        let element = elements[0];
        await element.click();
        await page.waitFor(111);
        alert("Program does not reach here.");
    });   
}
```

I am trying to implement a delay while working with puppeteer. However, it seems that code execution does not reach past the waitFor function. How could this be?

Comment: 1. `element.click()` does not return a Promise, so you need nor `await` before it. 2. Inside `page.evaluate()` function, variables from Node.js scope are not defined, so `await page.waitFor(111);` should throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

OP here, the following works:

```
await new Promise(function(resolve) {setTimeout(resolve, 2000)});
```